# Elastic search with docker does not start

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, cors, docker

I am retrieving details from elastic search in my angular application. which worked when i installed the elastic search on my local machine. I had to append the following lines to the elasticsearch.yml file to get it work with the angularApp.

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

Now elastic search server is installed with a docker. It also worked when i ran without adding those two lines. But when i added and restart the elastic search,
it gives me the following error.

```
{1.4.2}: Setup Failed ...
- SettingsException[Failed to load settings from [file:/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml]]
        ScannerException[while scanning a simple key; could not found expected ':';  in 'reader', line 7, column 3:
      http.cors.enabled: true
      ^]
org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsException: Failed to load settings from [file:/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromStream(ImmutableSettings.java:947)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromUrl(ImmutableSettings.java:931)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:77)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialSettings(Bootstrap.java:106)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:177)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 6, column 3:
      http.cors.allow-origin:"/.*/"
  ^
```

Here is the Elasticsearch.yml file on the server

[image]

Comment: as per your screen shot you missed to add `http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"` in .yml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two possible issues, which are not mutually exclusive:

First:

```
http.cors.allow-origin:"/.*/"
```

should really be

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
```

as YAML notation requires white space separation between the `:` and the value of a key-value pair.

Second, the error trace you provided suggests that there is leading white space in front of `http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"` that is inconsistent with its block per proper YAML notation.  It's more likely that the `http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"` needs to be devoid of leading white space if any exists (since I think `http` is typically a top-level block in Elasticsearch configuration files).